# How do I use Amazon Lex to take speech input from a customer and pass that information to a correct path using amazon connect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

So I am trying to streamline a customer support service by removing the need to listen to a set of options, and instead let the customer explain their issue, or say what they need support for. The list of possible service offerings exceeds 400 separate options. And I need to use Lex, Connect, and Lambda to solve this. (I do not want the customer to input a number corresponding to an option or service. I want them to explain their issue and be routed to a correct agent that can help them with the specific issue)

I went from a 100% manual input option to a speech to text option using Amazon Lex. Connect would say the list of options and the customer could say the option they needed help with instead of hitting a number on the phone. I converted all 12 or so options to speech to text. I read through the documentation and its not very helpful with my specific issue. (I also am not an expert in AWS and only just started learning a few weeks ago)

I would like to streamline this further by using Lex, connect, and lambda. But if I could avoid any one of those services, I would like to.

Answer (score 3):

For what you want to do, you will need all three because they each handle a different part of what you want to achieve.

**Connect** is the channel the user can call and use voice input that is converted to text and passed to your Lex bot. It also converts the Lex response into voice output back to the user.

The **Lex bot** handles intent recognition and slot value recognition and passes that information to your Lambda. (Very simple bots that only have single responses for each intent do not need Lambda.)

The **Lambda** function is where you can verify, parse, correct, and build the logic for the smart interaction you want to create. Any time you want to build a response based on the variations of user input more than just the recognition of intents, then you will need Lambda to do that.

Note that Lex is great for parsing user input in Lambda because Lex delivers the `inputTranscript` along with Lex's interpretation of the intent and slot values. However, Connect has to put the voice input through voice-to-text before delivering to Lex, so this can cause Lex to misinterpret a poorly converted voice input. So you will need to do a lot of testing of inputs and improve your validation code in Lambda to correct common mistakes.

(If you have a more specific problem/question, you should ask a new question and give the details of what you have tried, some code or examples and a clear question. You'll get better answers that way too.)